# How can a five-man special ops team sink an island?

Tags: science-fiction, geography

First of all thanks in advance. I need suggestions on how a five man special ops team can sink an island entirely.

Comment: We need to know a little more about your setting. Since you've said science fiction, what technological level are you giving them for example.

Comment: How big is the island? What kind of location is it in? Covered in ice, volcanic, coral?

Comment: The easiest thing I can think of is an island in a lake/river and they blow up a dam upstream.

Comment: You cant sink most islands as they are mountains attached to the sea bed. You can flood them. The only islands you can sink are ones made of ice or other floating material.

Comment: Is this about humans on Earth?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Is it easier for the Snarkoplus on Keppler-keyboardmash to sink an island than it is for humans? While this might not be a perfect fit, I'd love to see the answer discussing the differences

Comment: @Raditz_35 It certainly can make a difference if you are talking about people who have access basically to today's tech on Earth, or people who are 100,000 years further along in technological development compared to us.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling So this is basically what Sep... commented about. I kind of hoped you were aiming at some very exotic islands in some very exotic oceans with very exotic aliens (maybe having tentacles and acid breath would help somehow? idk) ;(. I might think about that one since it sounds very interesting. Thanks for the idea anyways

Comment: Depending on the size of the island, I guess you could kind of sort of briefly “sink” it by detonating a nuke offshore and allowing the resulting wave flood everything (of course, this is only temporary). Or you could try and actually nuke the island (again, depending on size) and just completely obliterate it. I think that would count as sinking it.

Comment: Start with Guam.  It's [already ready to capsize](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bs23CjIWMgA), which will make the job much easier.

Answer (score 3):

If the island is small enough and the SoF team has access to modern mechanized transport, they can always transport themselves and a thermonuclear device on location and find a way to place the device below ground (either a natural cave or cavern, or an underground bunker, service shaft or similar construction).

Of course these guys need to have been working out for a while, since to entirely remove an island from the face of the Earth needs something like "[Castle Bravo](https://infogalactic.com/info/Castle_Bravo)"

[image]

*Castle Bravo detonation*

OK, so maybe it isn't technically "sinking", but the crater will be well below sea level when finished.

Comment: You don't need modern mechanized transport.  Remember, this is an island--accessible to the sea.  Attach lighter-than-water (but not inflated!) floats to the bomb to give it a small positive buoyancy.  Attach an anchor to it to give a slight negative buoyancy.  Now you can swim the bomb to it's target.  (The slight negative buoyancy is within the range of what the divers can compensate for with their personal compensators.)

Comment: The Castle Bravo device was housed in a cylinder that weighed *23,500 pounds (10.5 long tons; 11.8 short tons)* and measured 179.5 inches (4.56 m) in length and 53.9 inches (1.37 m) in diameter. So yes, they will be needing a bit more than their bare hands......

Comment: We can do a lot better than that--with modern design 15mt should weigh no more than 3,000kg.  At neutral buoyancy they could move it--ever push a car?  Since it's 5-man team that's only 600kg/person.

Answer (score 2):

Either the island moves down or the sea level rises, both have their difficulties (understatement) and side effects.

### Islands are attached to the Earth

So first off we need to consider that to move an island down you need some way to **move enough of the material that lies between it and the sea bed**, they don't float so can't be 'sunk' as such. This all changes if you've designed a floating island but I expect you would have mentioned that.

The easiest way would be for the (small) island to be sitting on top of a **cave system** full of air or underground lakes - possible if your island is sitting on a layer of softer rock. If your island is on a fault line and your five man team is willing to put in a lot of time then [you could cause an earthquake](https://www.wired.com/2008/06/top-5-ways-that/) to bring the island down to fill the gaps the air/water once occupied and leaving the space above to be filled in by water.

Aside from that you're looking at **digging tunnels** beneath to create this effect, not a quick job and a high chance of being discovered - the collapse may not be total, it could sink in parts.

### Water rising

This is perhaps more likely...but again still difficult, its all a matter of volume and position. If your island is in the middle of a lake with a dam then you're in luck, the lake is a small area so a rise of a few meters is much less water than if your island is in the middle of the ocean. Blowing a dam or diverting a river are possible solutions for flooding a lake. Otherwise you're looking at melting ice caps and flooding everything that lies as low as your island.

The **consequences are important**. You **can't** raise the level of the ocean to flood an island and **expect the rest of the world to be fine**. Equally if an island sinks the volume of water that is going to start rushing about has to go somewhere. Earthquakes at sea have been known to cause tsunamis.

**All in all, if you're looking for a quick in and out job rather than a prolonged engineering project then you need explosives, a dam and your island to sit in the middle of a lake.**